# How do I prove that the image of a cyclic group has the following property?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

I have the following problem:

> Let $C_m$ and $C_n$ be two finite cyclic groups of cardinality $m$ and $n$. Let $d=\gcd(m,n)$ and $f:C_m\rightarrow C_n$ be a morphism of groups. Let $C_d\subset C_n$ be the unique subgroup of cardinality $d$. Show that the image of $f$ is contained in $C_d$.

I have just shown in a first part that $\forall x\in C_m$, $ord(f(x))|d$.

And I wanted to prove the statement as follows:

**Proof**

Let $g$ be a generator of $C_n$, i.e. $$\langle g \rangle=\{1,g^1,g^2,...,g^{n-1}\}=C_n$$Then since $C_d$ is a subgroup of $C_n$ we know that also $C_d$ is cyclic, to be more precise $$\{1,g^1,...,g^{d-1}\}=C_d$$ where $d<n$. Now let $x\in C_m$ and consider $f(x)$. Then since $f$ is a morphism of groups $$Im(f)<C_n\Rightarrow f(x)\in C_n \Rightarrow f(x)=g^i$$ for some $1\leq i\leq n-1$, but we just know that $ord(f(x))|d$ so we indeed have that $f(x)=g^j, \,\,1\leq j\leq d-1$. And this means that $f(x)\in C_d$, and thus $Im(f)\subset C_d$.

Does this work or is it completly wrong? It would be helpful if someone could take a look and write some comments.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

$Im(f)$ is a subgroup of $C_n$.
So all elements of $Im(f)$ have order dividing $n$.

Let $x\in C_m$ with order $l$. Then $l$ divides $m$.
Thus $f(x)^l = f(x^l) = f(1) = 1$ and so $f(x)$ has order dividing $l$ which divides $m$.

It follows that all elements of $f(C_m)$ have order dividing both $m$ and $n$ and so have order dividing $\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: Hello. I'm really sorry but I have just shown this in the first part, i.e. that $ord(f(x))|d$ Now I used it in the second. But your answer doesn't showed me if my proof is correct, I know maybe it is a bit to detailled but I wanted to be clear.

Comment: It would also be useful if one could tell me if and where I'm totally wrong or if it works. I think it's nice when you present other solutions so that I can see other possibilities. But without telling me what goes wrong in my proof I can't get better, i.e. I can't see my mistakes in further exercises.

Comment: Proof has two parts: $f(x)$ divides both $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Sure but this shows that $ord(f(x))|gcd(m,n)$. And I have shown this in a previous exercise